# multiple partial/child views in parent view in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, collections

I want to create a view page like below sketch. It has 3 sections .

Section 1: Table List - showing the list of available products

Section 2: Summary 1 - showing the 2 of newest launched products with short descriptions

Section 3: Summary 2 - showing the 3 of newest group discussion topics with short descriptions

[image]

For that I just followed [this Tutorial](http://pratapreddypilaka.blogspot.com/2011/11/partial-views-with-diefferent-models.html)

**I just tried to create show the table as partial view initially.later I hope to add other two sections.**

Designed model like this

```
public class DashboardViewModel
{
    public ProductTableViewModel ProductTable;

    public NewProductViewModel NewProduct;

    public DiscussionsViewModel Discussions;
}
public class ProductTableViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "S.No")]
    public string Product_ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product Title")]
    public string Product_Title_EN { get; set; }

    .....
}
```

for this I just created DAL like this

```
  public class DashboardData
    {
        public DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
        public ProductTableViewModel GetAllProducts()
        {
              var result = (from product in db.AB_Product
                            .....
                            select new ProductTableViewModel
                            {
                            .....     
                            }).ToList();

            return result;
        }
```

then I call it in controller like this .

```
    public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {

        ProductTableViewModel pdct = new ProductTableViewModel();
        DashboardViewModel puff = new DashboardViewModel();


        puff.ProductTable = pdct.GetAllProducts();

        return View(puff);    
    }
```

then I'm getting following errors

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   System.Collections.Generic.List<project_name.Models.ProductTableViewModel>'
>   to 'project_name.Models.ProductTableViewModel'

other error

> 'ProductTableViewModel' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetAllProducts' and no extension method 'GetAllProducts' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'ProductTableViewModel'

Comment: You `GetAllProducts()` method appears to be returning a collection of `ProductTableViewModel` (not a single `ProductTableViewModel`). You method should be `public List<ProductTableViewModel> GetAllProducts()` and the property in your model should be `public List<ProductTableViewModel> ProductTable;`

Comment: @StephenMuecke once I change like that getting following error in controller method `'ProductTableViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'GetAllProducts' and no extension method 'GetAllProducts' accepting a first argument of type 'ProductTableViewModel' could be found`

Comment: No it does not, but `DashboardData` does :). In anycase, your `GetAllProducts()` should not be inside a view model class. It should be a separate service.

Comment: And it would be a far better design to just have 3 separate action method that return partial view for each section, and then in the view use `@Html.Action("FetchAvaliableProducts", "Products")` etc

Answer (score 2):

Change type of pdct ProductTableViewModel  to DashboardData

```
DashboardData pdct = new DashboardData()
```

and

```
public class DashboardViewModel
{
    public List<ProductTableViewModel>  ProductTable;

    public NewProductViewModel NewProduct;

    public DiscussionsViewModel Discussions;
}
public List<ProductTableViewModel> GetAllProducts()
        {
              var result = (from product in db.AB_Product
                            .....
                            select new ProductTableViewModel
                            {
                            .....     
                            }).ToList();

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: I changed as you said but then getting following exception `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'project_name.Models.DashboardViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[project_name.Models.ProductTableViewModel]'`

Answer (score 2):

Here you are trying to return a **List of ProductTableViewModels** not a single item of **ProductTableViewModel**.So for first change the return type to `List<ProductTableViewModel>`

```
 public class DashboardData
 {
         public DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
         public List<ProductTableViewModel> GetAllProducts()
         {
               var result = (from product in db.AB_Product
                                .....
                             select new ProductTableViewModel
                             {
                             .....     
                             }).ToList();

               return result;
         }
 }
```

and then try to change your ViewModel as you want

```
public class DashboardViewModel
{
    public List<ProductTableViewModel> ProductTable;

    public NewProductViewModel NewProduct;

    public DiscussionsViewModel Discussions;
}
```

Comment: once I change like that getting following error in controller method `'ProductTableViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'GetAllProducts' and no extension method 'GetAllProducts' accepting a first argument of type 'ProductTableViewModel' could be found`

Comment: @kez but your method is in `DashboardData` not in `ProductTableViewModel`

Comment: I cannot understand you said

Comment: @kez on which object you are trying to call the GetAllProducts method ?

Comment: I didn't create a object using relevant model class , I just want to return the `var result`